# How to use $emit and $on of angularjs for two different controller stored in different path

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, emit

I have two views and its resp controller.
Say 
view1.html and its controller firstCntrl 
and 
view2.html and its controller secndCntrl.

In **view1.html**:

There is Link2 which will be redirected to view2.html if it is clicked.

```
<a href="#/view1" ng-click="emit()">Link1</a>  
<a href="#/view2" ng-click="emit()">Link2</a>
```

in ng-click I am calling emit function where I defined $emit as
**firstCntrl.js**

```
 app.controller("firstCntrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.emit = function() {
      $scope.$emit('send', { message: 'true' });
    };
 });
```

I want to send true from here and catch it in $on.

In **view2.html**

There are two div. say div one and div two.

```
<div ng-show="one">Hello</div>
<div ng-show="two">World</div>
```

What I want that If user clicks on first link then it should show the first div of view2.html

Or

if user clicks on second link then it should show sencod div of view2.html
View two have his own Secnd controller. I am struck here.
Help me in this How to do this. Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need emit here since firstCtrl and secondCtrl is a separated controller. In case there is no parent-child relation between your scopes you can inject $rootScope into the controller and broadcast the event to all child scopes.

**View1.html**

```
<a href="#/view1" ng-click="broadcastMsg(1)">Link1</a>  
<a href="#/view2" ng-click="broadcastMsg(2)">Link2</a>
```

**firstCtrl**

```
app.controller("firstCntrl", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.broadcastMsg = function(id) {
      if (id == 1) 
          $rootScope.$broadcast('send', 'One');
      else 
          $rootScope.$broadcast('send', 'Two');
    };
 });
```

**View2.html**

```
<div ng-show="showOne">Hello</div>
<div ng-show="!showOne">World</div>
```

**parentCntrl**

Use $scope.on instead of $rootScope.on to prevent memory leak issue.

```
app.controller("parentCntrl", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
      $scope.$on('send', function (evt, message) {
            if (message == 'One') 
                $scope.showOne = true;
            else
                $scope.showOne = false;
      });
 });
```

**secondCtrl**

```
app.controller("secondCntrl", function ($scope) {
      $scope.showOne = $scope.$parent.showOne;
 });
```

Comment: one thing I noticed that if I clikcking on msg1 or msg 2 but it showing only World. no Hello

Comment: I m facing one bug, that $broadcast is not working on single click. I have to click two times for that. @digit

Comment: It's not bug i think. It's the delay of execution. Can you debug the code by putting console.log('enter') in rootscope.on. What u will get after clicking at the 1st time?

Comment: No. Im getting it after clicking it on 2nd time @digit

Comment: I have put my $broadcast  at then end of controller. So whats happening basically is when $broadcast starts it redirected to start of controller. Ans on second click its searching for $on

Comment: Do you have parent controller?

Comment: yes my header controller is home controller and its included through ng-include in other view @digit

Comment: Try put rootscope.on in parent controller.

Comment: its stop working if I am using $rootScope.$on @digit

Comment: I know the issue is. I guess the other controller which is supposed to receive the event is not yet instatiated when you are $broadcasting the event.

Comment: put rootscope.on in parent controller . Let me update my answer

Comment: I implemented this. frstCntrl is my parent controller so I posted $broadcast and $on on same controller and in second controller I write last code block which you edited yesterday. But by this method view is not loading although url changing.