# $broadcast and $on is not working on single click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, emit

In my angularjs application I am using $emit and $on to show to different section of page.

For code refer to this link.

[How to use $emit and $on of angularjs for two different controller stored in different path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647183/how-to-use-emit-and-on-of-angularjs-for-two-different-controller-stored-in-dif/41647329?noredirect=1#comment70556908_41647329)

Green tick code is working but its required two click in intervel then its working.

It should work on one click.

Comment: Can you create a plunker or a fiddle with a minimal example?

Comment: @Mohammed Are you using $emit or $broadcast?

Comment: I can. But thing is in my application I am redirecting a page to another page through a href tag.This is wont possible in fiddle. Else if I created jsfiddle without without redirecting it on another page then it will surely work But for my app I want to work with redirection. @SidharthPanwar

Comment: @Mohammed Can't you use $location for redirection? Is there a specific need to use $emit/$broadcast?

Comment: yes actually in my header file say view1 there is link1 and link2. Both link will be redirected same page say view2. Only difference is if I click one link one hen my view2 will load "Hello" and if I click on view2 my view2 will load "World". @SidharthPanwar